# Uploading Data With CSV File to Parse

Tags: ios, csv, parse-platform

I am trying to upload a csv file to my parse database. I created all versions of CSV files (mac, windows, comma delimited vs.) but whenever I try to import, all the columns are merged as one column in parse. Below are the views of my csv file and the view in parse. How can I distribute them separately to separate columns. Any ideas?

[image: excel image]

[image: parse view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have this problem is because you have ';' as your separator, not a ',' how it is supposed to be in CSV.

This can unfortunately only be changed through the operating system settings and not on excel export (on both mac and windows machines).

The most feasible way for you would be to export to a 'tab-separated' file and then just Find-Replace the 'tabs' with ','

(You can find and replace 'tabs' in most editors by just copy pasting an existing tab into the search field)

Comment: Thank you Nils, thats right, when I changed the seperates to comma with a text editor it worked fine.